# Does LLVM initialize local variable for primitive types?

Tags: objective-c, llvm

Does LLVM initialize local variable for primitive types?

I get a warning:

```
Variable is uninitialized when used here.
```

but when I `NSLog` it, it does show `0`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error indicates, LLVM does not initialize local variables automatically.

See http://clang.llvm.org/compatibility.html.

Specifically

> Programs must explicitly initialize all local block variables before
>   they are used, as with other local variables.